# Is scanl1 really partial?

Tags: haskell, partial-functions

[According to the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_of_partial_functions), the [`scanl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl1) function is partial. I don't understand what inputs result in bottom, though. For list functions, I'm used to the problem inputs either being empty lists (like for `head`) or infinite ones (like for `reverse`). However, `scanl1` seems to handle both of these types of lists correctly. Is this actually a partial function? If so, what's an example of an input that will result in bottom?

Comment: From the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#scanl1), it doesn't look partial. Everything seems to be correctly handled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a mistake on the wiki. `scanl1` is in fact total. (I've updated the wiki.)